# Failed to build out Blender executable from source?

Tags: startup-file

all, I actually successfully build **blender-2.92.0** with **cmake**, everything goes on well, but failed to find the **executable** . The following are all what I found under folder **bin**.

```
➜  bin ls
2.92  bpy.so  datatoc  datatoc_icon  makesdna  makesrna  msgfmt  tests
```

Can anybody give me some suggestions?

Thank you very much

Cheers
Pei

Comment: It appears you have built blender as a python module. _eg_ you could open a python shell in the bin folder and `from . import bpy`

Comment: you might want to include the cmake command line you used.  Any args?